# Mongo Aggregation where query is having child elements that create root

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a query that is getting generated at the backend where in the project the path is building based on the root element.

```
{
  data: [
    {
      $project: {
        'Source.Code': {
          $ifNull: [
            '$Source.Code',
            '$$REMOVE'
          ]
        },
        'Source.Description': {
          $ifNull: [
            '$Source.Description',
            '$$REMOVE'
          ]
        },
        'Source._id': {
          $ifNull: [
            '$Source._id',
            '$$REMOVE'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Above is the projection and as you can see Source is created based on the fields inside `Source` document. My issue if as I'm doing for child fields I want to check `$ifNull` on `Source` and remove it if there is no document at all. Something like

```
      {
        'Source': {
          $ifNull: [
            '$Source',
            '$$REMOVE'
          ]
        }
```

I'm not sure how I can build a query like this in aggregation. Here Source is an object, it has multiple fields and I want to check for null on `Source` and if it's not null then on all of its fields and add accordingly to `Source`.

```
{
Source: {
    Code: "Code",
    Description: "test",
    _id: "SomeID"
  }
}
```

If Description is null then

```
{
Source: {
    Code: "Code",
    _id: "SomeID"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Now I want to add a case where I have object Source and it has fields which can be translatable. What I mean by translatable is that they are i18n fields which has language fields inside it. So consider the below example

```
{
Source: {
    Code: "Code",
    Description: {
       "en":"test",
       "fr": "testfr",
       "def": "test"
},
    _id: "SomeID"
  }
}
```

So now from previous query that I have menctioned

```
{
  data: [
    {
      $project: {
        'Source.Code': {
          $ifNull: [
            '$Source.Code',
            '$$REMOVE'
          ]
        },
        'Source.Description': {
          $ifNull: [
            '$Source.Description.en',
            '$$REMOVE'
          ]
        },
        'Source._id': {
          $ifNull: [
            '$Source._id',
            '$$REMOVE'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, Source.Description.en would have .en appended to the path to fetch en from Description. How can I change the query for this edge case?

Comment: is Source field array of object type?

Comment: It is an object. I want to check $ifNull on all the fields inside it and on it as well. So it would be like first check if Source is null or empty and if not then check if its fields are null on every field inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$objectToArray` to convert `Source` object to array key-value format
- `$filter` to iterate loop of above converted array and filter by value is not null
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value back to object
- `$addFields` to get `en` from `desscription`
- `$cond` to check if its empty object then remove otherwise return

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      Source: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$Source" },
            cond: { $ne: ["$$this.v", null] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { "Source.Description": "$Source.Description.en" } },
  {
    $project: {
      Source: {
        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$Source", {}] }, "$$REMOVE", "$Source"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EC7Nu4I9Xqf)

Comment: what if I have a translatable field where I need to append locale like .en to the fields inside the object. I want to check for them as well. how can I do that?

Comment: I just updated the question with an edit, please have a look. Thank you

Comment: see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WDmoVzE8NIM), just need to add a stage.

Comment: but it is adding the empty object of Source in the result. I want to remove if the Source is null. $addFields is helping with language documents but it is adding empty objects if it is null

Comment: see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EC7Nu4I9Xqf).

Comment: Thank you very much that should solve the issue.